# Win 7 BSOD stucks at dumping

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Recently Ive been getting frequent bsods, which always gets stuck at dumping without finishing it, with most of them showing no error messages. This never happened before i upgraded to new rams, but 2 passes of memtest86 turned out fine. Tried reinstalling windows, problem still there. Tried initiating a manual crash, and that did create a successful dump. The SSD win 7 is on doesn't seem to have any problems, crystaldisk says its healthy. Varied the cpu multiplier between stock and +500Mhz, crashed regardless. Left voltage control to auto. Im fairly sure its a hardware problem, just cant pinpoint which specific part(s).

The specs-

- Windows 7 x64 (1 day old)
- 955 x4 BE c3 (running at stock) (3.5 years old)
- GA-970A-D3 (1.5 years old)
- Gigabyte 6950, unlocked to 6970 (still at 6950 speeds) (<3 years old)
- 2x4GB 1600 CL9 HyperX Blu (running at 11-11-11, default motherboard setting) (<1 month old)
- Plextor M5s (around 5 months)

Comment: I'm confused about the problem: Is it that Windows is crashing, or that the crashes do not create a successful memory dump?

Comment: @K.A Both actually. It crashes way to often and randomly, while failing to create valid dumps.

Comment: Does Windows display the error code(s)/error name(s), or does the dumping process fail before then?

Comment: @K.A It goes all the way to actually dumping the memory, but stops at 10-35%. Sometimes it stops at Initializing memory dump. It does show the error code, but rarely the error names.

Comment: how large is your pagefile?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Its 9GB

Answer (score 1):

If your not doing anything with the dump files turning creation off or selecting Small memory dump (256 KB) will speed things up and be less likely to fail. No point in waiting on dump file creation if your just letting them get overwritten while testing.

If you populated more RAM slots try with just the new RAM in the same slots used previously. Also try half the RAM and swap them around to see if it's specific stick or slot. Reset the BIOS to defaults and reconfigure to get rid of any lingering old configuration.

[image]

Comment: Did a bios fail-safe configuration reset, swapped the RAM around (never had the old sticks installed with the newer ones). Im running furmark and prime95 at the moment. Tried playing BF4 before, and it caused the PC to restart 5 minutes in, without any blue screens. I want the dump files, since it might say whats causing the crashes. Im tempted to just go and buy a new proc, but I dont want to come back and see it not work again. I doubt its a memory problem, since I did memtest86 twice before, on slower than rated timings, with no errors.